# Blender 3d view port rotation issue

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have a model under construction - this is ok but I've done something to the way it relates to other objects in the 3d view.
With just the model in the view all appears to be fine when I rotate the view in any direction.
If I add two new objects to the scene and rotate the view, the new objects move as expected in relation to each other but the model always appears to be in front of the other two objects - it never passes behind the other two objects.
If I duplicate the model, the two models behave as you would expect but both are always in front of the others in the scene.
I think I've set some parameter on the model but I can't see it!

Comment: Welcome to the site.This sounds like a pivot point issue. I'd suggest doing a search of Blender Stack Exchange using the search parameter "Pivot point", and review the questons and answers shown by the search.

Comment: It sounds like you've turned on x-ray for your object.

Comment: I spent hours yesterday playing with the pivot point - wasn't that. But it was x-ray!!!! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've turned on *X-Ray* display mode for your object.  You can toggle X-Ray mode under the *Object* properties tab > *Display* Rollout.

[image]

X-Ray display draws the object in front of all other objects (which don't have X-Ray enabled).  It is most often useful for armatures to keep them from getting lost inside the meshes they control.